# Is an interface considered 'empty' if it inherits from other interfaces?

Tags: interfaces, inheritance

Empty interfaces are generally consider bad practice, as far as I can tell - especially where things like attributes are supported by the language.

However, is an interface considered 'empty' if it inherits from other interfaces?

```
interface I1 { ... }
interface I2 { ... } //unrelated to I1

interface I3
    : I1, I2
{
    // empty body
}
```

Anything that implements `I3` will need to implement `I1` and `I2`, and objects from different classes that inherit `I3` can then be used interchangeably (see below), so is it right to call `I3` *empty*? If so what would be a better way to architecture this?

```
// with I3 interface
class A : I3 { ... }
class B : I3 { ... }

class Test {
    void foo() {
        I3 something = new A();
        something = new B();
        something.SomeI1Function();
        something.SomeI2Function();
    }
}

// without I3 interface
class A : I1, I2 { ... }
class B : I1, I2 { ... }

class Test {
    void foo() {
        I1 something = new A();
        something = new B();
        something.SomeI1Function();
        something.SomeI2Function(); // we can't do this without casting first
    }
}
```

Comment: Being unable to specify several interfaces as type of a parameter/field etc. is a design flaw in C# / .NET.

Comment: I think the *better way to architecture this* part should go into a separate question. Right now the accepted answer has nothing to do with the question title.

Comment: @CodesInChaos No, its not as there are two ways to do this already.  One is in this question, the other way would be to specify a generic type parameter for the method argument and the use the where restriction to specify both interfaces.

Comment: Does it make sense that a class that implements I1 and I2, but not I3, should *not* be able to be used by `foo`? (If the answer is "yes", then go ahead!)

Comment: @Andy Whilst I don't entirely agree with CodesInChaos's claim that it's a *flaw* as such, I don't think that generic type parameters on the method are a solution - it pushes the responsibility of knowing a type used in the method's implementation onto whatever is calling the method, which feels wrong. 
Perhaps some syntax like `var : I1, I2 something = new A();` for local variables would be nice (if we ignore the good points raised in Konrad's answer)

Comment: @Kai The caller always has to know, and this is what compilers ensure automatically.  At the end of the day there's no way (in a strongly typed language) to call Foo(string) unless you know that foo is in fact being passed a string.  I think the I3 interface is better than the generic parameter approach, but at least in C# there are multiple ways to accomplish what is needed already.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

> Anything that implements I3 will need to implement I1 and I2, and objects from different classes that inherit I3 can then be used interchangeably (see below), so is it right to call I3 empty? If so what would be a better way to architecture this?

"Bundling" `I1` and `I2` into `I3` offers a nice (?) shortcut, or some sort of syntax sugar for wherever you'd like both to be implemented.

The problem with this approach is that you can't stop other developers from explicitly implementing `I1` *and* `I2` side by side, but it doesn't work both ways - while `: I3` is equivalent of `: I1, I2`, `: I1, I2` is not an equivalent of `: I3`. Even if they're functionally identical, a class that supports both `I1` and `I2` will not be detected as supporting `I3`.

This means that you're offering two ways of accomplishing the same thing - "manual" and "sweet" (with your syntax sugar). And it can have a bad impact on code consistency. Offering 2 different ways to accomplish the same thing here, there, and in another place results in 8 possible combinations already :)

```
void foo() {
    I1 something = new A();
    something = new B();
    something.SomeI1Function();
    something.SomeI2Function(); // we can't do this without casting first
}
```

OK, you can't. But perhaps it's actually a good sign?

If `I1` and `I2` imply different responsibilities (otherwise there would be no need to separate them in the first place), then maybe `foo()` is wrong to try and make `something` perform two different responsibilities in one go?

In other words, it could be that `foo()` itself violates the principle of Single Responsibility, and the fact that it requires casting and runtime type checks to pull it off is a red flag alarming us about it.

**EDIT:**

If you insisted on ensuring that `foo` takes something that implements `I1` and `I2`, you could pass them as separate parameters:

```
void foo(I1 i1, I2 i2)
```

And they could be the same object:

```
foo(something, something);
```

What does `foo` care if they're the same instance or not?

But if it does care (eg. because they're not stateless), or you just think this looks ugly, one could use generics instead:

```
void Foo<T>(T something) where T: I1, I2
```

Now generic constraints take care of the desired effect while not polluting the outside world with anything. This is idiomatic C#, based on compile-time checks, and it feels more right overall.

I see `I3 : I2, I1` somewhat as an effort to emulate [union types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_type) in a language that doesn't support it out of the box (C# or Java don't, whereas union types exist in functional languages).

Trying to emulate a construct that's not really supported by the language is often clunky. Similarly, in C# you can use extension methods and interfaces if you want to emulate [mixins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixin). Possible? Yes. Good idea? I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

If there were particular importance in having a class implement both interfaces, then I see nothing wrong with creating a third interface that inherits from both.  However, I would be careful to not fall into the trap of overengineering things.  A class could inherit from one or the other, or both.  Unless my program had plenty of classes in these three cases, it is a little much to create an interface for both, and certainly not if those two interfaces had no relation to one another (no IComparableAndSerializable interfaces please).

I remind you that you can create an abstract class as well that inherits from both interfaces, and you can use that abstract class in place of I3.  I think it would be wrong to say that you shouldn't do it, but you should at the very least have a good reason.

Comment: Huh? You certainly can implement two interfaces in a single class.  You don't inherit interfaces, you implement them.

Comment: @Andy Where did I say that a single class can't implement two interfaces?  For what concerns the use of the word "inherit" in the place of "implement", semantics.  In C++, inherit would work perfectly fine since the closest thing to interfaces *are* abstract classes.

Comment: Inheriting and interface implementation are not the same concepts.  Classes inheriting multiple subclasses can lead to some weird issues, which is not the case with implementing multiple interfaces.  And C++ lacking interfaces doesn't mean the difference goes away, it means that C++ is limited in what it can do.  Inheritance is an "is-a" relationship, while interfaces specify "can-do."

Comment: @Andy Weird issues caused by collisions between methods implemented in said classes, yes.  However, that is no longer an interface not in name nor in practice.  Abstract classes which declare but not implement methods is in all sense of the word except name, an interface.  Terminology changes between languages, but that doesn't mean that a reference and a pointer aren't the same concept.  It's a pedantic point, but if you insist on this, then we'll have to agree to disagree.

Comment: "Terminology changes between languages" No, it doesn't.  OO terminology is consistent across languages; I've never heard an abstract class meaning anything else in each OO language I've used.  Yes, you can have the semantics of an interface in C++, but the point is there's nothing preventing someone from going and adding behavior to an abstract class in that language and breaking those semantics.

Comment: @Andy And there's nothing stopping someone from adding defaults to interfaces in Java.  I fail to see your point, and quite frankly it seems a pedantic one at that.

Comment: Good for Java; you can't do that in .Net interfaces.  Just because a language allows something doesn't mean its necessarily a great thing to do.  Like the `new` keyword in C#.  And yes, it is a very nitpicky thing, and most times you don't need to care about it, but it can bite you in insidious ways in the times it is important, which is why they are NOT the same thing in the languages.  I mean if there really wasn't any difference, we wouldn't even have interfaces right?  Sadly I'm not explaining well why it matters, and I can't find the link that did a good job of it.

Answer (score 2):

> Empty interfaces are generally consider bad practice

I disagree. Read about [marker interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marker_interface_pattern).

> Whereas a typical interface specifies functionality (in the form of
>   method declarations) that an implementing class must support, a marker
>   interface need not do so. The mere presence of such an interface
>   indicates specific behavior on the part of the implementing class.

Comment: I imagine the OP is aware of them, but they're actually a bit controversial. While some authors recommend them (eg. Josh Bloch in "Effective Java"), some claim they're an antipattern and legacy from times when Java had no annotations yet. (Annotations in Java are roughly the equivalent of attributes in .NET). My impression is that they're much more popular in Java world than .NET.

Comment: I use them once in a while, but it feels kinda hackish - the downsides, off top of my head, are that you can't help the fact they're inherited, so once you mark a class with one, all its children get marked as well whether you want it or not. And they seem to encourage bad practice of using `instanceof` instead of polymorphism